# Getting non repeating values (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying some aggregation techniques to get the non repeating values on my database, but I always get same result before I put some aggregation techniques like ltrim.

My query:

```
SELECT 'Data'
       ||','||LTRIM(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CREATE_TIME),'MM/dd/yyyy'))
       ||','||LTRIM(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CLOSE_TIME),'MM/dd/yyyy'))
       ||','||COUNT(*)
FROM APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_TICKET
WHERE CREATE_TIME BETWEEN SYSDATE -7 AND SYSDATE
AND CLOSE_TIME BETWEEN SYSDATE -7 AND SYSDATE
GROUP BY TRUNC(CREATE_TIME), TRUNC(CLOSE_TIME)
ORDER BY TRUNC(CREATE_TIME), TRUNC(CLOSE_TIME);
```

Here's the result that I always get:

```
Data,01/17/2014,01/17/2014,16
Data,01/17/2014,01/20/2014,1
Data,01/17/2014,01/21/2014,2
Data,01/18/2014,01/18/2014,2
Data,01/19/2014,01/19/2014,1
Data,01/19/2014,01/20/2014,1
Data,01/19/2014,01/21/2014,1
Data,01/20/2014,01/20/2014,6
Data,01/20/2014,01/21/2014,2
Data,01/20/2014,01/22/2014,1
Data,01/21/2014,01/21/2014,13
Data,01/21/2014,01/22/2014,1
```

Instead of, (here's the result that I really need)

```
Data,01/17/2014,01/20/2014,1
Data,01/18/2014,01/18/2014,2
Data,01/19/2014,01/21/2014,1
Data,01/20/2014,01/22/2014,1
Data,01/21/2014,01/22/2014,1
```

The table structure.

```
CREATE_TIME (DATE)
CLOSE_TIME  (DATE)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do?  You can use lower case letters as well.

Comment: i don't want repeat the date, i just want to get every single date

Comment: Aggregation technique like `LTRIM`? `LTRIM` is not an aggregation function... Also, what do you want with, for example, `01/17/2014,01/17/2014`? Discard? Add up? Why pick `01/17/2014,01/20/2014`?

Comment: Your counts don't add up.  How do you get the count?

Comment: And about the count?  how you want to group them?

Comment: Removing close time from your GROUP BY clause satisfies ur requirement, but count is still illogical. Can you post the table description as well?

Comment: I want to group them by date, wherein the latest date is on top. @MaheswaranRavisankar

Comment: i got an error ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression" @MaheswaranRavisankar when i follow your suggestion

Comment: I posted an answer can you try it please.

Comment: The count part is not yet clear.. Can you give the table description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 'Data'
||','||LTRIM(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CREATE_TIME),'MM/dd/yyyy'))
||','||LTRIM(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MAX(CLOSE_TIME)),'MM/dd/yyyy'))
||','||COUNT(TICKETS_CLOSED)
FROM APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_TICKET
WHERE CREATE_TIME BETWEEN SYSDATE -7 AND SYSDATE
AND CLOSE_TIME BETWEEN SYSDATE -7 AND SYSDATE
GROUP BY TRUNC(CREATE_TIME)
ORDER BY TRUNC(CREATE_TIME)
```

Comment: thanks for your query, i got the answer that i need, and i add a new line in your query ||','||COUNT(DISTINCT TRUNC(CREATE_TIME)) to get the result of create time. thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to group by CREATE_TIME and get the most recent CLOSE_TIME for that date. Try removing the CLOSE_TIME from your group by statement and select the MAX(CLOSE_TIME) instead.